# How does decidable equality works with List.remove?

Tags: coq

I am starting in Coq and discovered that I have to provide a proof of decidable equality to use `List.remove`. e.g.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Import List.ListNotations.

Inductive T : Set := A | B | C.

Lemma eq_dec : forall a b : T, {a = b} + {a <> b}.
Proof.
  destruct a, b; try (left; reflexivity); try (right; congruence).
Qed.

Definition f (xs : list T) : list T := List.remove eq_dec A xs.
```

This now type-checks, but I don't understand how to use it.

```
Theorem foo : f [ A; B; C ] = [ B; C ].
Proof. reflexivity.
```

gives me

```
Error: Unable to unify "[B; C]" with "f [A; B; C]".
```

How does this decidable equality work and what is some good source I could read about it?

## Edit 1

I just learned about the [`decide equality`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.6.1/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic174) tactic, which

> solves a goal of the form `forall x y:R, {x=y}+{~x=y}`, where R is an
>   inductive type such that its constructors do not take proofs or
>   functions as arguments, nor objects in dependent types.

So  `eq_dec` can rewriten:

```
Lemma eq_dec : forall a b : T, {a = b} + {a <> b}.
Proof. decide equality. Defined.
```

## Edit 2

I just learned about the [`Scheme Equality for T`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.6.1/refman/Reference-Manual015.html#hevea_command235) command, which

> Tries to generate a Boolean equality and a proof of the decidability
>   of the usual equality. If identi involves some other inductive types,
>   their equality has to be defined first.

So `T_beq : T -> T -> bool` and `T_eq_dec : forall x y : T, {x = y} + {x <> y}` can be automatically generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you used the `Qed` command to end your proof.  This causes the `eq_dec` function you just defined to become opaque, thus preventing Coq from simplifying expressions involving it.  A simple solution in this case is to use `Defined` instead:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Import List.ListNotations.

Inductive T : Set := A | B | C.

Lemma eq_dec : forall a b : T, {a = b} + {a <> b}.
Proof.
  destruct a, b; try (left; reflexivity); try (right; congruence).
Defined.

Definition f (xs : list T) : list T := List.remove eq_dec A xs.

Theorem foo : f [ A; B; C ] = [ B; C ].
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

You can check Adam Chlipala's [CPDT book](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Subset.html) to learn more about this style of programming.

There is also an alternative approach, which I personally prefer. The idea is to program normal equality tests that return booleans, and prove after the fact that the tests are correct.  This is useful for two reasons.

1. It allows reusing standard boolean operators to write these functions; and
2. functions that involve proofs (like `eq_dec`) can interact badly with Coq's reduction machinery, because the reduction needs to take the proofs into account.

You can read more about this alternative style in the [Software Foundations book](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/IndProp.html#lab223).  You can also have a look at the [mathematical components](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/) library, which uses this style pervasively -- for example, to define a notion of [type with decidable equality](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can also keep the proof of decidable equality opaque, but in this case you have to use another tactic than `reflexivity` to prove your result.

In the same context as your example, try this:

```
Theorem foo : f [ A; B; C ] = [ B; C ].
Proof.
unfold f; simpl; case (eq_dec A A);[intros _ | intros abs; case abs; auto].
case (eq_dec A B);[discriminate | intros _].  
case (eq_dec A C);[discriminate | intros _].
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Knowing that this solution exists may be very useful when you want to reason more abstractly about the equality between elements of your type and when computation cannot do everything for you.

Comment: Could this pattern be automated using Ltac? i.e. a `reduce_eq_dec x y` that would detect whether `x` is syntactically equal to `y` and use either the `case` or `discriminate` approach you highlighted?

Comment: yes, and using 'try' you don't even have to be able to tected whether x and y really are equal.